# Malloc of struct allocates no memory to attributes

Tags: c, memory

I'm currently working with data structures and so far, allocating memory has never been much of an issue, until now. Essentially, upon allocating memory to a new struct variable, I'm unable to do anything with its' attributes. More specifically, for both attributes it says "<Unable to read memory>".

I have a struct called Graph with two attributes, one is a pointer-to-pointer (which I want to represent a matrix) and the other is a pointer of another struct GraphElement.

I have a function createGraph that returns a pointer to a Graph. In the function I allocate memory to the new Graph, as well as to the matrix attribute.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct GraphElement
{
    int key;
}Vertex;

typedef struct Graph
{
    int** adjacencyMatrix;

    Vertex* allVertices;
}Graph;


Graph* createGraph(int vertices)
{

    Graph* newGraph = malloc(sizeof(Graph));

    size_t rowColumnSize = sizeof(int*) * vertices;

    newGraph->adjacencyMatrix = malloc(rowColumnSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
    {
        newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * vertices);
    }
}
```

In my main I want to create a Graph with a matrix of size 5*5:

```
int main()
{
    Graph* graphTest = createGraph(5);
}
```

The problem lies in the createGraph function, more specifically in the first row where i try to allocate memory to the new graph using malloc. When that line is executed, the says in the Locals window that for both attributes of newGraph it is ". Thus, the program crashes as I get to the third line in createGraph. Previously, I've had no problems allocating memory to structs and immediately after allocate memory or assign values to its attributes, but for some reason I can't get it to work here. Help appreciated!

EDIT: I was asked to produce a minimal reproducible example. I'm a bit new to the programming world but hopefully this is satisfactory.

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Data structues

typedef struct GraphElement
{
    int key;
}Vertex;

typedef struct Graph
{
    int** adjacencyMatrix;

    Vertex* allVertices;
}Graph;


// Functions

Graph* createGraph(int vertices)
{
    Graph* newGraph = malloc(sizeof(Graph));

    size_t rowColumnSize = sizeof(int*) * vertices;

    newGraph->adjacencyMatrix = malloc(rowColumnSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
    {
        newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * vertices);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Graph* graphTest = createGraph(5);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem as a single code snippet, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: What you've posted looks fine.  Please update your code with a [mcve] that others can compile and run *as is* and get the same results you do.

Comment: Where in your code do you allocate (or, at least, initialize) the `allVertices` member?

Comment: Your `createGraph()` function does not `return` a pointer to the allocated memory (nor anything else).  If your compiler is not warning you about that then you should get a better compiler, or maybe stop suppressing warnings.

Comment: `createGraph` does not contain a `return` statement, so it does not return a value. It is conceivable that optimization by the compiler may then result in the program behaving as you describe in the debugger. You should fix it and test again.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I forgot to add `return newGraph`, but the compiler never reaches so far, it always crashes in the third line where I try to do something with `adjacencyMatrix`

Comment: The function `malloc` requires `#include <stdlib.h>`. It is possible that on your platform `stdlib.h` is being implicitly included by `stdio.h`, in which case this error is harmless on your platform. However, since you appear to be ignoring warning messages emitted by the compiler, it is also possible that you are ignoring a warning message that the function `malloc` is being implicitly defined, which may cause your program to crash.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It works now that I added `#include <stdlib.h>`, completely forgot about that! As mentioned, I am quite new to this. Is there a way for me to mark your comment as the solution or is that only possible to do with answers?

Comment: @Hypherix: Re “the compiler never reaches so far”: As my comment states, optimization may cause this behavior. The C standard does not require compilers to generate programs that execute in the same order as the source code. The behavior of the program you displayed in this post is not defined by the C standard, so the compiler would be allowed to generate any code for it. Fix the error and test again.

Comment: @Hypherix: Using the non-existant return value of the function `newGraph` in the function `main` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) **for your entire program**. So it is at least theoretically possible that a missing `return` statement is the cause of a crash, even if it only occurs later in the program.

Comment: @Hypherix: It is not possible to accept a comment as an answer. Please note that your compiler should have generated at least a warning about an "implicit function definition" of `malloc` or something like that. I suggest that you take all warning messages emitted by your compiler very seriously, because most compilers are very good about pointing out errors in your code. Did you receive such a warning message from the compiler? If so, what was the exact warning message?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the only warning I received when not having `#include <stdlib.h>` was "'malloc' undefined; assuming extern returning int".

Comment: @Hypherix: That warning is important. Do not ignore warnings. Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: @Hypherix: In future, whenever you see the warning message about a library function from the C standard library being undefined, you should assume that you forgot to `#include` a file and fix that immediately, by consulting the documentation  to see which header file to `#include`. For example, [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) states that `malloc` requires the header file `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @Hypherix: In future, when asking a question on Stack Overflow, if the compiler provided a warning message which you don't understand, I suggest that you also post that warning message. These warning messages often contain valuable information about what could be wrong. Generally, the programs you write should not have any warning messages, and if they do, you should attempt to fix them. Having a warning message is generally a sign that something is wrong about your program.

Comment: I learned a lot, thanks for everyone's input and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important problesm is that you do not return from the function and you do not check the result of `malloc`.

```
typedef struct GraphElement
{
    int key;
}Vertex;

typedef struct Graph
{
    int** adjacencyMatrix;

    Vertex* allVertices;
}Graph;

Graph* createGraph(size_t vertices)
{

    Graph* newGraph = malloc(sizeof(*newGraph));
    if(newGraph)
    {
        newGraph -> allVertices = NULL;
        newGraph->adjacencyMatrix = malloc(vertices * sizeof(newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[0]));
        if(newGraph->adjacencyMatrix)
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
            {
                newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[0][0]) * vertices);
                if(!newGraph->adjacencyMatrix[i]) 
                {
                    /* handle allocation error */
                    /* for example free allocated memory */
                }
            }
    }
    return newGraph;
}
```

I would also suggest using the objects in the `sizeof` instead of types (like in my example).
You need to include `stdlib. h` to have prototypes of malloc family functions. Otherwise, the compiler will assume that the function returns `int` instead of a pointer and it is an Undefined Bahavior